# unable to to get the working of Annyang.js library

Tags: javascript, annyang

My question is straight forward

How annyang.js is working? is there any api that annyang is using internally?

Answer (score 0):

Annyang is placed on top of the [Google Web Speech API](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html). This is why it  only works in browsers, that are using said API (e.g. Google Chrome)

It simplifies the use of it, by offering you a set of functions, that are described [here](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/docs/README.md).

Try the [example site](https://www.talater.com/annyang/)... If there is a big red note at the bottom of the page, your browser does not support it. Also you have to give it permission to use your microphone. A small popup should display, where it asks you for permission.